# Why won't my index.html connect to my index.css file?

Tags: python, html, css, django

My `index.html` won't connect to my `index.css` for some reason.  I can't see why.  Maybe it's the path of files or something.  I apologize for such a noob question.  My `index.css` file has a small bit of code just to test out and see if it works.

[image]

Here's my `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>The Page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'index.css' %}">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="Enter first name" name="firstName">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Last Name:</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Enter last name" name="lastName">
            </div>

            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember">Remember me</label></div></br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </div>

            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's my `index.css` file:

```
html {
    background: chocolate;
}
```

Here's my `settings.py` file:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '+-9mn+q&u@lw2_=s7&=zin5d7oxbt#v@9jg%2+a7=#noqd_jyf'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'music.apps.MusicConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]



MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'tyran.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'tyran.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Can you reach the .css file through your browser developer tools?

Comment: Did try by dragging and dropping it in ur page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should [load the static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/) with correct way in Django, better to split static files and templates. Here is one solution based on your case:

Fristly, under `music` folder, create `static` folder, put your static file `index.css`.

After that, change the loading css file with this way in your `index.html`:

```
{% load static%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'index.css' %}">
```

Then, it will load the static file.

**Update:**

make sure `index.css` is in the path: `tyran/music/static/index.css`

Comment: can you check your console to see what's the error message?

Comment: `index.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

That's the error I'm getting in the console.

Comment: what's the  STATIC_URL in your `settings.py`?

Comment: `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

Comment: can you update your project image and your new html code in the question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146808/discussion-between-bojack-and-tiny-d).

Answer (score 0):

Just give it a hard path instead:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/music/templates/music/index.css">`

Answer (score 0):

Django is looking for a file called "index.css" relative to your project root, not the template directory. See this documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) about setting up a STATIC_URL directory to tell Django where to look for static assets.

Answer (score 0):

**There's nothing wrong in the code.**
I copied your code and ran on my machine. It works fine.

[image]

There's no problem in your code. The connection also is too correct. Try doing it in other IDE or manually.

Comment: hmm, I don't know why it's not working for me.  I tried restarting my server and refreshing my page, it still didn't display the background color.